# how to get month from date in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get month from my date variable.

```
date=Date.now();

console.log(date); 
>>2019-12-04T08:55:48.972Z
```

I want to get the month from this date but when I'm using getMonth(), I'm getting error.

```
console.log(date.getMonth());
error:- getMonth is not a function
```

Comment: see `var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMonth();`

Comment: `Date.now()` returns a number, I'm surprised you're getting a string result in your first code block

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
let date= new Date();

console.log(date.getMonth());
```

```
let date= new Date('2019-10-04T08:55:48.972Z');

console.log(date.getMonth()+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need date object for this.

Try this:

```js
let date = new Date();

console.log(date.getMonth()+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the `.now`.
It should be `date = new Date();`